# how to see css change?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, sass

I have to create a blog with a navbar, pics and text. My question is about the navbar. I can't give a personal style to my link.

**CSS:**

```
.site{
    background-color: #E8CF8C;
}
.navi_link{
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    size: 300%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
  <?php
    $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items(
      get_nav_menu_locations("main-menu")["main-menu"]  
    );     
    foreach ($items as $menuItem):
  ?>
  <li class="navbar_li">
    <a class="navbar_li navi_link" aria-current="page"
      href="<?= $menuItem ->url ?>"><?= $menuItem ->title ?></a>
  </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

How to customize my link? I am using an underscores.me them and sassified it.

Comment: Count the number of closing curly braces in your CSS above.

Comment: you should close .site selector in your css file and did you import your css file in head tag? be careful about your questions stackoverflow isn't a tutorial website.

Comment: Is `size:` a CSS property? I may be wrong here but I've never used it or come across it

Comment: sorry, i edit the css part of my question and I edit my CSS file. but nothing happened ...

Comment: true. the "size" property isn't available for for a font. so, I changed that for a "font-size" but nothing happened...

Comment: Ok, from what I can gather you are trying to style the underline of you links. If that is the case look into `text-decoration` and its related/similar properties https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration